# tcl to handle embedded system firmware upgrade through xmodem

Tags: tcl, xmodem

I am attempting to handle device firmware upgrade for one of my embedded system devices through Xmodem in TCL. I have searched for the solution the whole day but had no luck to succeed.

Does anyone have any ideas to share?

Thanks.

Comment: Xmodem? :why_would_you_do_that.meme.png:

Comment: What code have you written and what problems are you having this it?

Comment: The device only supports the way for firmware upgrade via Xmodem. I don't have idea how to handle xmodem in tcl so there is no code to share here. Basically, sending the firmware through xmodem to the device. I have successfully upgraded firmware with tera-term already. I intend to develop an automation to handle it.